# Commerce shipping by weight and country

Tags: commerce

I'm having trouble finding a solution for combining location & weight-based shipping with drupal commerce.

I need to have three shipping zones (DK, EU, ROW) with individually priced weight steps inside each zone (0-500g, 500-1000g, 1000-2000g, 2000-5000g).

I've gone through a bunch of tutorials and looked at other forums where people have similar requests. But haven't found a solution yet - which should be possible for such a 'simple' problem, right?

To sum up I need advice on how to configure the following shipping calculation rules:

- Free Shipping (no weight)
- DK Shipping (1-500g)
- DK Shipping (501-1000g)
- DK Shipping (1001-2000g)
- DK Shipping (2000-5000g)
- EU Shipping (1-500g)
- EU Shipping (501-1000g)
- EU Shipping (1001-2000g)
- EU Shipping (2000-5000g)
- ROW Shipping (1-500g)
- ROW Shipping (501-1000g)
- ROW Shipping (1001-2000g)
- ROW Shipping (2000-5000g)

I can't figure out how to check for a line item's weight in a rule?

I've got Shipping, Flat Rate, Physical Product, Physical Fields and Rules Extra enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing 12 rules as @nvahalik suggested. Here's an export of one of them. Doing the others is just a matter of cloning this rule and changing weight, territories and shipping price accordingly

```
{ "rules_dk_shipping_1_499g" : {
    "LABEL" : "DK shipping (1-499g)",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Commerce Checkout", "Commerce Payment" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "rules",
      "commerce_physical",
      "commerce_order",
      "commerce_line_item",
      "commerce_shipping"
    ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:type" ], "value" : "shipping" } },
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-shipping-service" ],
          "value" : "by_weight"
        }
      },
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "field" : "commerce_customer_shipping"
        }
      },
      { "commerce_physical_rules_order_weight_comparison" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "operator" : "\u003E=",
          "value" : "1",
          "unit" : "g"
        }
      },
      { "commerce_physical_rules_order_weight_comparison" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "operator" : "\u003C",
          "value" : "500",
          "unit" : "g"
        }
      },
      { "commerce_order_compare_address" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "address_field" : "commerce_customer_shipping|commerce_customer_address",
          "address_component" : "country",
          "operator" : "is one of",
          "value" : "DK"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : "3300",
          "component_name" : "shipping",
          "round_mode" : "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: thanks Kristoffer for the export from your rules but i would like to put the same configuration for a drupal commerce website, mixing weight and location calculating shipping from a total cart.
As a newbee, could you please help me with a tutorial explaining how you have configurate your shipping total cost based on different weight and locations.
Thanks

Comment: It's actually in the rules too. Look at the amount lines. Those are the prices in Danish kroners. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

This would be doable with 12 individual rules (3 countries x 4 sizes = 12 rules). You can also try this module: [Commerce shipping Province weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_province_weight).

Shipping is one of the few areas where Commerce tends towards more customized solutions. But perhaps that one will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nvahalik. I'd prefer the Rules solution to avoid installing yet another module and to avoid a lot of configurations. I've elaborated my question with some specific issues with my rules-knowledge. Hope you've got time to take a look.

Comment: Wait, nailed it I think - will test and provide my solution here when it's tested